# Checking that the image of a curve is not contained in a hyperplane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth curve, $n \geq 2$. I would like to find an easy to check condition such that the image of $\gamma$ is not contained in an $n-1$ dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. for every such subspace $H \subset \mathbb R^n$ it holds that
$$
\gamma([0,1]) \cap (\mathbb R^n \setminus H) \neq \emptyset.
$$
Is there any theory in this direction?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Consider $\gamma$ at $n$ random points in $[0,1]$, and calculate the determinant of those points: $\det\neq 0$ means that $\gamma$ definitely is not contained in an $n-1$-dimensional subspace; $\det =0$ means that all those points lie in some lower-dimensional subspace, and it may well contain the whole curve.

Comment: If the image of $\gamma$ is contained in a proper subspace then so is its derivative. You could use any linear algebra method to test if the tangent vectors are in a plane.

Comment: Unless you tell us more about how your curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is specified and what sorts of information about it can be easily computed, it's hard to give advice about an 'easy-to-check condition'.  For example, it's a simple matter to construct examples of smooth $\gamma$ that don't lie in a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but for which uniform sampling from $[0,1]^m$ to test $m$ points $\gamma(t_1),\ldots,\gamma(t_m)$ for linear independence will have a 99.99999% probability of 'yes', but still $\gamma([0,1])$ does not lie in a proper subspace.

Answer (score 13):

A curve $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is called non-degenerate if $\alpha'$ and $\alpha''$ are linearly independent at every point.

A curve parametrized by arc-length is a Frenet curve if $\alpha''\neq 0$ everywhere (i.e. if it has non-vanishing curvature).

One can prove that a curve $\alpha$ is non-degenerate iff its arc-length parametrization is a Frenet curve.

The non-degenerae curve $\alpha$ is contained in a plane if and only if its torsion equals zero. That is $\alpha$ is contained in a plane if and only if
$$
\det (\alpha',\alpha'',\alpha''')=0
$$
at all points.

You can find this result is almost any textbook on differential geometry of curves and surfaces. I am pretty sure the result has a generalization to curves in higher dimensions, but I do not remember details.

Answer (score 4):

I would check existence of one nondegenerate point; it means that $\alpha'(t_0),\dots,\alpha^{(n-1)}(t_0)$ are lineraly independent.

If such point exists, then find a vector $w$ perpendicular to all $\alpha'(t_0),\dots,\alpha^{(n-1)}(t_0)$, and then check that $\langle w,\alpha'\rangle =0$ --- if yes, then yes; if no, then no.

If your curve has only degenerate points, then I would try to use elementary geometry.